# The following code is working in Windows Phone 8 but when i convert into Windows Phone 8.1 NavigationContext is Not Working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

When i try to declare NavigationContext i am getting error in Windows Phone 8.1

```
public static string GetFeedbackMailMessage(NavigationContext context)
{
    string VideoTitle = string.Empty;
    string LinkType = string.Empty;
    string VideoUrl = string.Empty;
    string ShowTitle = string.Empty;
    string FeedbackMessage = string.Empty;

    context.QueryString.TryGetValue("chno", out VideoTitle);
    context.QueryString.TryGetValue("LinkType", out LinkType);
    context.QueryString.TryGetValue("uri", out VideoUrl);
    context.QueryString.TryGetValue("title", out ShowTitle);
    if (context.QueryString.TryGetValue("chno", out VideoTitle) && context.QueryString.TryGetValue("LinkType", out LinkType) && context.QueryString.TryGetValue("uri", out VideoUrl) && context.QueryString.TryGetValue("title", out ShowTitle))
    {
        FeedbackMessage = "Movie Name : " + ShowTitle + "\n" + VideoTitle + " \n " + "http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=" + VideoUrl + "\n";
    }
    return FeedbackMessage;
}
```

Comment: Please check the link below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633409/windows-phone-8-error-with-navigationcontext-querystring-trygetvalue

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Now you can pass only a single string the parameter which you can extract and obtain all these values.

Comment: Hello Jestin C.I thanks for your replay.. your refered code is working in windows phone 8, But not working in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: I guess you found the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829513/does-not-contain-a-definition-for-navigationcontext-in-windows-phone-8-1/28829785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string ShowTitle = NavigationContext.QueryString["title"];
```

Check this also : http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/05/23/windows-phone-8-1-frame-page-navigationhelper-suspensionmanager.aspx